# How to convert code from Unity 4 To Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to installed Unity 5. I have some problem in the following code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        var air = other.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageManager>();
        if(air){
            air.HP += HPFill;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: So whats the problem? Any errors in console?

Comment: @PawełMarecki: Error: `UnityEngine.Component.collider' is obsolete: `Property collider has been deprecated. Use GetComponent<Collider>() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'

Comment: So why don't you use `GetComponent<Collider>()` instead?

Comment: Look at this `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` here you got `Collider` as parameter and next line you try to access `other.collider`. Anyway you should be able get componenet like this `var air = other.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageManager>();`. I'm not able to test this but you can try for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `var air = other.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<DamageManager>()` **with** `var air = other.GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject.GetComponent<DamageManager>();`

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var air = other.GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject.GetComponent<DamageManager>();

        if (air)
        {
            air.HP += HPFill;
        }
    }
```

Comment: other is already the Collider component and a Component has a GetComponent member method so no need to reach for the gameObject.

Comment: I know it is. I translated what he had to exactly what it would look like in Unity 5. other.GetComponent<DamageManager>(); should do it but I provided the exact translation from what he provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var air = other.GetComponent<DamageManager>();
```

The collider in your code is actually redundant since other is already the collider component. It is like asking the reference to reach itself. And no need either to use the gameObject reference since Collider is a Component and then contains a GetComponent method.

The new versions of Unity are removing all component reference but transform and gameObject as they are always there.